# What are the changes in ICONS Superpowered Roleplaying: Assembled Edition?

Tags: edition-comparison, icons

*ICONS Superpowered Roleplaying* is a superhero RPG derived from FATE and featuring random character generation and simple gameplay. What are the differences between [the original edition](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/81475/ICONS-Superpowered-Roleplaying), released in 2010 and [The Assembled Edition](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/131765/ICONS-Superpowered-Roleplaying-The-Assembled-Edition), released in 2015?

Answer (score 1):

From the store page at Green Ronin, you get a link to Steve Kenson's blog, which nicely summarizes the changes from the original game to Assembled: https://stevekenson.com/2014/05/05/icons-assembled-whats-different/

After glancing through it, I can't wait to pick this up and give it a shot with my gaming group, it looks fun!

Comment: That is a useful link. Could you please put some of the highlights in your answer (e.g. the change in dice rolling)? Just in case that blog post ever gets deleted, we'd want your answer to still be useful.